# Confusion about definition of mapping

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions

**Definition :**

**Mapping :** Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-empty sets. If $f$ is a relation between $A$ and $B$ then an element $x$ of $A$ may be related to one element or no element or many elements of $B$ by the relation $f$.

A relation $f$ with the property that each element $x$ of $A$ is related to **exactly** one element $y$ of $B$ is said to be a *mapping* from $A$ to $B$ OR a function from $A$ to $B$.

Now consider  , $f:\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0] \to \mathbb R$ by $f(z)=\arg(z)$. I know that for any $z\in \mathbb C \setminus(-\infty,0]$ $\arg(z)$ is NOT unique. So from the above definition here $f$ is NOT a function.

Again I know $\arg(z)$ is a multivalued function. It violates the definition of function ?

Where is the fallacy ?

Answer (score 3):

Relations which are called 'multivalued functions' are indeed no functions, since there is at least one point $x$ in the domain which has at least two points $y_1,y_2$ in the codomain related to it, i.e. $y_1$ and $y_2$ are multiple values of the non-function $f$.

You are correct: Without specifying a branch, $\arg$ is not a function.

Comment: To make arg a function, it can be restricted to take values only in $(-\pi,\pi]$. It is then called the main branch or principal value of the argument and may be written Arg(z).

Answer (score 0):

Well, one can easily say that **arg**(*z*) is a function that has sets of real numbers as range, and that all the elements in the image of **arg** are countably infinite and are of the form *a* + *n* π  with integer *n* and *a* between negative and positive pi.